# Extract a certain part of a string after a key phrase

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I was wonder the best way one could look for a specific phrase in a string and then take everything after it and store that in a new variable.
For example if...

```
var str = 'hello how are you doing the what is a dinosaur search Jim carrey';
```

Everything after 'search ' or 'search for ', in this case 'Jim carrey' should be stored in a new var— let's call it val.

Also, if there are two or more instances of the phrase 'search ' or 'search for ' then only store what is after the latest one in val.

For example: if str = 'welcome I am search pie recipie search quick chili recipie' then val would be 'quick chili recipie'
Or
If str = 'Today is 78 degrees search good weather and sunny in other words a perfect day for search for when does summer end' then val would be 'when does summer end'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this RegExp :

```
var str = 'Today is 78 degrees search good weather and sunny in other words a perfect day for search for when does summer end';
var arr = str.split(/ search (for){0,1}/);

alert(arr[arr.length-1]);
```

Comment: Works perfectly and just how I wanted. Thank you. I should brush up on my regex because I was going to use .split();

Comment: Could you explain to me what the different symbol in the regex mean?
What is the difference between your regex and this one: /\bsearch (for)\b/gi

Comment: First of all, I have to mention that I edited my answer to a better pattern. second, in my pattern, you can have `for` at most once (in previous pattern you could match `search forforforfor` which was wrong). And YOUR pattern  wont match `PREFIXsearch forPOSTFIX` :)

Comment: I added `{0,1}` to be more specific about what we are learning :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var str = "welcome I am search pie recipie search quick chili recipie";
var m = str.split('search');
alert(m.slice(-1));
```

or

```
  str.split('search').pop() // will do same thing
```

[`working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/mdfZB/1)

Answer (score 1):

Legendinmaking's answer returns the phrase with a space at beginning and to return everything after search or search for use this

```
var str = 'welcome I am search pie recipie search quick chili recipie';
 var param='search';
 var param1='search for';
 var n=str.lastIndexOf(param);
 var n1=str.lastIndexOf(param1);
 n=Math.max(n,n1);
 alert(str.substring(n+param.length + 1,str.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure it is the best way of doing it but it works and you can try to change srt value at jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uguzup/1/edit

```
var str = 'Today is 78 degrees search good weather and sunny in other words a perfect day for search for when does summer end';
var val = str.split('search for').slice(-1)[0].split('search').slice(-1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str = 'welcome I am search pie recipie search quick chili recipie';
    var param='search';
    var n=str.lastIndexOf(param);
    alert(str.substring(n+param.length,str.length));
```